# Safe to stall stepper motor when driver has current limit?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

So I am making a system where a stepper motor is powering a linear actuator. I am looking to buy a suitable stepper motor driver. I would like to start the linear actuator calibrated from a "zero" position. To calibrate I want to drive the actuator to max extension and from there count forward/backward steps to know actuator position. To know when the motor hits the max obstacle I could:

- Use driver with stall detection: Drive until stall is detected. That's "zero"
- Or drive actuators for a sufficiently long time into the wall so I know it's at max. But relying on current limiting of driver to keep safe current level while motor is stalling at max extension.

Question: Is is bad to keep a stepper motor stalled for 1 minute even though I have a current limiting stepper motor driver,  like [this one](https://www.pololu.com/product/2134), that is set to a current safe for motor

Comment: if the motor cannot withstand the stall current, then no

Comment: @jsotola I think you're right. Would you consider filling this out into a full answer instead of just putting in a short comment? Filling it out to be a full answer with some background info will provide better understanding for people who find this in the future.